# How to combine two tables that have distinct data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

1. `tbl_vacancies_details`
2. `tbl_filled_vacancies`

I want show a graph that contains the total count of vacancies and filled counts in each year. How can I write a SQL query for that.

```
 tbl_vacancies_details

    Id | Year      | Count |
    ------------------------
    1  | Jan-2014  |  10   |
    2  | Jun-2014  |  5    |
    3  | Dec-2015  |  9    |

    tbl_filled_details

    Id | Join_Date | UserId |
    ------------------------
    1  | Mar-2014  |  1     |
    2  | Dec-2014  |  6     |
    2  | Dec-2014  |  15    |
    3  | May-2016  |  3     |
```

My desired output is

```
Year | Total | Filled |
-----------------------
2014 | 15    | 3      |
2015 | 3     | 0      |
2016 | 0     | 3      |
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL + DML for sample data, And more importantly, to remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: Why would a column called year have a month in it?? And I don't understand the role of the id column in the filled_details table.

Comment: (i) Are the date values stored as strings? (ii) How do you derive the **Filled** values from the given input? (For 2014 it seems to be the count, for 2016 the verbatim value.)

Comment: Data type of Year is DATE Id is just an PRIMARY KEY AND its IDENITY @Zohar Peled

Comment: tbl_vacancies_details.Year and tbl_filled_details.Join_Date are  DATE datatype. But my outbut should contain only year value @Abecee

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT
  year Year
  , (SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM tbl_vacancies_details WHERE YEAR(dt) = years.year) Total
  , (SELECT COUNT(userID) FROM tbl_filled_details WHERE YEAR(join_date) = years.year) Filled
FROM
  (SELECT
    YEAR(dt) year
  FROM tbl_vacancies_details
  UNION
  SELECT
    YEAR(join_date)
  FROM tbl_filled_details) years
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9f1d/1)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    (CASE         
        WHEN vac.year not null then to_char(vac.Year,'YYYY')         
        ELSE to_char(det.Year,'YYYY')) as Year,
        sum(vac.Count) as Total,
        det.Count as Filled       
    FROM
        tbl_vacancies_details  vac  FULL      
    OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                to_char(fil.Join_Date,'YYYY') as Year,
                count(*) as Count             
            FROM
                tbl_filled_details as fil             
            GROUP BY
                to_char(fil.Join_Date,'YYYY')           
        ) det ON det.Year = vac.Year       
    GROUP BY
        to_char(vac.Year,'YYYY')
```

I think this showcases the idea of how to do it but I'm not sure that it is runnalbe query. You will have to find functions for transforming the date based on your format.

It full outter joins tbl_vacancies_details by year with the inner select (which counts the occurances of vac in tbl_filled_details for each year) and then displayes both results for each year

Edit: I asumed that tbl_filled_details has case by case records of vacation and tbl_vacancies_details has already sums of vacations

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a `union all` query with aggregation:

```
select yyyy,
       sum(total) as total,
       sum(filled) as filled
from ((select year(year) as yyyy, count as total, 0 as filled
       from tbl_vacancies_details
      ) union all
      (select year(join_date) as yyyy, 0 as total, 1 as filled
       from tbl_filled_details
      )
     ) x
group by yyyy;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4e58a/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

Note:  I would advise you to not name your columns `count` and `year` because these are used for other purposes in SQL.